# Need for String.Format in C# to throw compile time error for mismatch in arguments

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, string.format

Is there any way to to add custom compile time errors when there is a mismatch in number of arguments passed to String.Format in C#

Eg:

```
String.Format("{0} and {1} are my pets", animal);
```

the above line should throw an error since we have passed only one argument `"animal"` , while it is expecting two `{0},{1}`.. but in reality it throws just run time errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FxCop / Code Analysis will pick this up. And yes, you can do that at compile time in VS Premium / Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: added screenshot - hope that's ok

Comment: I have configured that to throw a build error in a TFS2015 automated build environment, so as to fail a gated check-in whenever it is detected. IMO when the first argument is a string literal, and the number of items in the variable argument list is given and mismatching, it can never be correct - it would inevitably fail at runtime. in the end, it is kind of a syntax error.

Comment: A little to the party, but is this possible in the VS2022? Trying to find the configuration in the Professional version of it but no luck so far.

Answer (score 3):

Resharper will add an IDE warning for that. However, that isn't a compiler error; what you have written is perfectly fine as far as the compiler is concerned.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't add custom compile time error. Its a logical error and will throw exception

Edit:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("test{0} and {1}","test"));
```

it will throw:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list

Comment: @Joey, yes it will throw "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list"

Comment: Which kinda contradicts your »it's not a serious problem, just a logic error«.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible idea, but you could create five or so extension methods called `Format1`, `Format2`, etc. and have the parameters hard coded and passed to a normal `String.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

Format strings are a feature of certain methods in the .NET class library. The compiler doesn't know anything about them. The compiler can only throw errors regarding things that have to do with the *language* itself, not how you invoke certain library functions.